# Strapi auth provider Disabled

Tags: reactjs, strapi

I followed tutorial.

https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/plugins/users-permissions.html#providers

I cloned frontend and enabled providers, add client and secret ids as in tutorial.

After that, I got an error message on frontend. However, email login/register works well.

```
{
   "statusCode": 400,
   "error": "Bad Request",
   "message": "This provider is disabled.",
   "data": "This provider is disabled."
}
```

I use MongoDB.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Go to the admin panel and click on Users Role and Permission. Click on the Provider Tab and enable the provider.

Comment: I said I already enabled that option.

Comment: Is there anybody who can help me?

Comment: I can help you.

Comment: What provider are you trying to enable and check? @AlexsanderKnezevic

Comment: I have the same issue and I noticed Strapi about it : https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/6323